# Can an Earth Kineticist (Pathfinder Society Occult Playtest) sunder at range?

Tags: class-feature, ranged-attack, pathfinder-society

I have an Earth Kineticist from the PFS Occult Playtest. I have in several modules helped save my party by diverting my kinetic blast attacks to target enemy weapons and or armor (Sundering). For mechanic clarification, my kinetic blast has an extended range up to 120 feet, the attack is classified as a regular ranged attack, and ignores any spell resistance. EDIT: the kinetic blast is treated as magical for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction and can be applied as bludgeoning, slashing, or piercing damage specified with each attack chosen at the time each attack is made.

The adjudication for [sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Sunder) reads as such:

> You can attempt to sunder an item held or worn by your opponent in place of a melee attack. If you do not have the Improved Sunder feat, or a similar ability, attempting to sunder an item provokes an attack of opportunity from the target of your maneuver.
>
> If your attack is successful, you deal damage to the item normally. Damage that exceeds the object's Hardness is subtracted from its hit points. If an object has equal to or less than half its total hit points remaining, it gains the broken condition. If the damage you deal would reduce the object to less than 0 hit points, you can choose to destroy it. If you do not choose to destroy it, the object is left with only 1 hit point and the broken condition.

Energy Attacks

Energy attacks deal half damage to most objects. Divide the damage by 2 before applying the object's hardness. Some energy types might be particularly effective against certain objects, subject to GM discretion. For example, fire might do full damage against parchment, cloth, and other objects that burn easily. Sonic might do full damage against glass and crystal objects.

Ranged Weapon Damage

Objects take half damage from ranged weapons (unless the weapon is a siege engine or something similar). Divide the damage dealt by 2 before applying the object's hardness.

While the GM has so far allowed me to sunder with my kinetic blast, at range, the target was not afforded an attack of opportunity, the damage was not halved, and I do not have the improved sunder feat. Should I expect table variation of ranged sunder attempts or am I simply not allowed to attempt to sunder at range as written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAW, no, you cannot perform ranged sunder attacks without an additional ability that lets you (like the [Archer fighter archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo---fighter-archetypes/archer)'s Trick Shot ability). That's the only current way to get a ranged sunder ability, but it would be fair to propose a feat or class archetype that grants it.

Comment: Thank you I have proposed such a build archetype or feat on the Paizo forum to do just that.

Comment: In D&D 3.5e, Trick Shot *was* a feat (in Complete Warrior, from memory).